# Add more than one filter to a query using same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Background

I am trying to create a filter that searches database and displays results based on certain ID's

### CODE

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, A.AcquiredDate, GetDate())  >=5  AND A.AssetTypeID = 7 AND A.CategoryID = 5
```

### What i would like it to say:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, A.AcquiredDate, GetDate())  >=5  AND A.AssetTypeID = 7 AND A.CategoryID = 5 AND A.CategoryID = 4
```

### Problem

After adding second part of code `AND A.CategoryID = 4` the query spits out 0 records.

### Question

How do I filter both `A.CategoryID = 5 AND A.CategoryID = 4`?

Comment: You're probably looking for `AND A.CategoryID IN (4,5)`. CategoryID field for a record cannot be 4 and 5 at the same time. Most likely you mean OR. The above can also be rewritten as `AND (A.CategoryID = 4 OR A.CategoryID = 5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `Where condition` like this. Use `OR` operator or `IN` Clause  instead of `AND`

The `AND` operator displays a record if both the **first condition AND the second condition are true.**

The `OR` operator displays a record **if either the first condition OR the second condition is true.**

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, A.AcquiredDate, GetDate())  >=5  
AND   A.AssetTypeID = 7 
AND   (A.CategoryID = 5 or A.CategoryID = 4)
```

OR

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, A.AcquiredDate, GetDate())  >=5  
AND   A.AssetTypeID = 7 
AND   A.CategoryID IN (5,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OR or an IN. So:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, A.AcquiredDate, GetDate())  >=5  AND A.AssetTypeID = 7 AND (A.CategoryID = 4 OR A.CategoryID = 5)
```

Or:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, A.AcquiredDate, GetDate())  >=5  AND A.AssetTypeID = 7 AND A.CategoryID IN (4, 5)
```